# Javascript bug in Google Maps integration

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to get the following code to work (which looks really straightforward but it does not work like it is supposed to)

Please help me out here :

```
function findLocationAddress(myLatLng)
    {
        var formattedAddress='MY HOUSE ADDRESS';

        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': myLatLng},function(results, status) 
        {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
            {
                if (results[1]) 
                {
                    formattedAddress = results[1].formatted_address;
                }
            } 
        });

        alert(formattedAddress);
        return formattedAddress;
    }
```

The above function should return the new value of **formattedAddress** but it is still returning "MY HOUSE ADDRESS"

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the geocoder.geocode request is asynchronous, and you are returning your value synchronously. Try something like this:

```
function findLocationAddress(myLatLng)
    {
    var formattedAddress='MY HOUSE ADDRESS';

      geocoder.geocode({'latLng': myLatLng},function(results, status) 
      {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {
          if (results[1]) 
          {
          formattedAddress = results[1].formatted_address;
          alert(formattedAddress);
          // then do what you want (e.g. call a function) here
          // e.g. doMyNextThing(formattedAddress);
          }
        } 
      });
    }
```

Above code sample tested and working.

You can also use a callback function, if you like, to define what happens after the address is found (this will make the function much more reusable)

```
function findLocationAddress(myLatLng, callback)
    {
    var formattedAddress='MY HOUSE ADDRESS';

      geocoder.geocode({'latLng': myLatLng},function(results, status) 
      {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {
          if (results[1]) 
          {
          formattedAddress = results[1].formatted_address;
          callback(formattedAddress);
          }
        } 
      });
    }

findLocationAddress(myLatLng, function(formattedAddress){
  // Do what you want with the result here
});
```

This may be obvious but note also `results[1]` will give you the second result, as the array index starts at 0 (this may be intended behaviour)